# how to check that user can not input more than one decimal or dot in html web page

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have web page with input field i want that user can input number in that but number should not contain two decimals like 10.0.0 mean it can only enter .one time not two times any idea how we can fix this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Validate the input field via javaScript function where you validate the field value via Regex.
A simple tutorial should help you with Regex http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Check input mask of jansy http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#inputmask.

Comment: it is  validation for only numbers in W3schools what if if user enter two dots

Comment: if `value.replace('.','').indexOf('.') === -1` is true, then it is valid

Comment: or `value.split('.').length == 2`, then it is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming input element el is already assigned to a variable v.

```
if (1 < v.match(/\./g).length) {
  alert("Multidots found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function run(element) {
            var regex = /\d*\.?\d?/g;
            element.value = regex.exec(element.value);

    }
```

call this function on `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the event of the keypress or keyup and check if the key pressed is a dot. If it is entered the first time, you could assign a boolean centinel to true, and cancel the keypress event for future dots.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
var str = '10.0.0';
str.indexOf('.');
```

which gives how many times its contain in a string.

Comment: it should show how many times . is it tells if it si after two digits are three digits

Comment: try alert(str.indexOf('.'));

Comment: this is incorrect. indexOf() returns the location/ index position of the sought character. in this example the returned 2 is dot position 2, and not the dot count 2. to prove this is incorrect use str = '10.0.0.0.0' in your jsfiddle code and it will still return 2 incorrectly.